# Make the template folder if angular be functional as views folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm trying to use the erb template on my angular templates folder, but the functionality is limited, for example,
The <% link_to 
is working 
but devise methods or even raw('sdmdslkc') pops an error that the method is not found.

for example
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
work on views but not in angular templates (says destroy_user_session_path method not found)

Whats missing ? is it fixable?

Answer (score 0):

let me see if i understand, u have some template with some tags that belongs to another language that is not angular, html, or js. if so then it is not fixable because angular sends an ajax to bring that html file and injects it to your page, alot after any server has rendered any part of the page.

my suggestion for a work around is to try and tell angular to take a server page, say it was with asp.net and i would like some server tags i would tell angular that the template is somepage.aspx while making sure that my page evetually returns plain html.

Comment: You understand well, it's just a ruby specific thing I guess.

Comment: if i did understand well then its about the way angular works as i tried to explain, nothing to do with ruby :). why dont u try my workaround?